# Minimize function is still showing bar

Tags: vb.net, toolbar, vb.net-2010, system-tray

Just made a simple application that sits in the tasktray. It shows the PC name, IPV4 address, and Domain. I made it so that when a user closes the application it only closes to the tray unless EXIT is selected from the contextmenustrip. It worked totally fine. Then I added some code to try something and it didn't offer much so I removed it. Once removed the application stopped minimizing to the tray. It makes no sense because it's exactly as the code was prior. And the maxmimize button is supposed to be disabled.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Obtain Hostname and assign to label
    strHostname = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
    lblHostname.Text = strHostname.ToString

    'Obtain IP Address and assign to label
    Dim ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName)
    Dim strIpAddress = ipHostEntry.AddressList.FirstOrDefault(Function(ip) ip.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    If strIpAddress IsNot Nothing Then
        strIpAddress.ToString()
    Else
        lblIP.Text = "No IPV4 Address could be retrieved"
    End If

    lblIP.Text = strIpAddress.ToString

    'Obtain Domain and assign to label
    strDomain = Environment.UserDomainName
    lblDomain.Text = strDomain.ToString

End Sub

Private Sub form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing

    'This checks to see if the form was closed by the MENU (Boolean = True)
    ' or if the user selected "X" which will minimize to task tray
    'This is needed because X cannot be disabled without losing Minimize function

    If BoolClose = False Then
        e.Cancel = True
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized

    Else
        End
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click

    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal

End Sub

Private Sub NotifyIcon1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon1.MouseClick
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Minimizing a window will just put it in your taskbar. If you want to completely hide it, just set the Visible property as false and it should work

Comment: I guess I will go that route. It is odd that it was working prior. But thank you that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have your form's `ShowInTaskBar` Property set to `false`. But this will show you app in the taskbar and not in the system tray. Maybe [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75822/Create-a-System-Tray-Application-in-VB-NET) helps you.